# User recent activities - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 MySQL tables representing: photos a user post, videos a user post, comments a user post and I need to view the 10 (20, 30, 40...) most recent activities by the user.

For example in photos table may be composed by:

```
user_id | photo_id   | photo_path | photo_name | date_added
   5    |     18     |  /photos   | pht_18.png |  2009-02-12
   5    |     21     |  /photos   | pht_21.png |  2009-02-15
   5    |     29     |  /photos   | pht_29.png |  2009-03-30
```

the videos table

```
user_id | video_id   |  video_url       |   date_added
   5    |     36     |  youtube.com/... |   2009-01-09
   5    |     48     |  youtube.com/... |   2009-02-18
   5    |     90     |  youtube.com/... |   2009-03-19
```

the comments table

```
user_id | comment_id |   comment     |  date_added
   5    |     6      |   hi!         |  2009-02-11
   5    |     11     |   great photo |  2009-02-13
   5    |     19     |   nice shot!  |  2009-03-28
```

As you can see the 3 tables have different number of attributes, so how can I do the union? and while fetching the query result how can I understand to which table it belongs to?

So in the user profile page I'd like to show his recent activities of course ordered by DATE DESC this way:

```
2009-09-01: user posted a video
2009-11-02: user posted a comment
2009-12-02: user posted a photo
2009-13-02: user posted a comment
2009-15-02: user posted a photo
2009-18-02: user posted a video
2009-19-03: user posted a video
2009-28-03: user posted a comment
2009-30-03: user posted a photo
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You should probably edit your question to show that the different tables have some unique columns, per your comment below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A MySQL UNION query could work here:

```
(SELECT `user_id`, `date_added`, 'photo' AS `type` FROM `photos` WHERE `user_id` = uid) UNION
 (SELECT `user_id`, `date_added`, 'video' AS `type` FROM `videos` WHERE `user_id` = uid) UNION
 (SELECT `user_id`, `date_added`, 'comment' AS `type` FROM `comments` WHERE `user_id` = uid)
 ORDER BY `date_added` DESC;
```

Then you'd wind up with a result set like

```
user_id | date_added | type
    5   | 2009-01-03 | photo
    5   | 2008-12-07 | video
    5   | 2008-11-19 | comment
```

and so on. (actually you can leave `user_id` out of the SELECT if you want, of course)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have separate tables in the first place? That's probably a mistake in database design.

[***EDIT***: As it turned out through comments and a question edit, the OP had a valid reason to maintain three tables. Further advice about this removed.]

To solve your problem you can use UNION or UNION ALL:

```
(SELECT 'photo'   AS item_type, date_added, user_id FROM photos)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'video'   AS item_type, date_added, user_id FROM videos)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'comment' AS item_type, date_added, user_id FROM comments)
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Comment: I've done 3 different tables becouse each element (photo,video,comment) has different attributes

Comment: anyway, while fetching the results how can i understand to wich table it belongs to?

Comment: It's in the fist column, as a string.

Comment: @d03boy: The information that this may not be a mistake was revealed after my post. From the question alone I could only come to this conclusion. Had you read all the comments, you would have known. I think you are a little fast with the down votes.

Comment: Down votes can be undone -- when your answer gets changed. An answer that doesn't properly reflect the revision of the question isn't useful.

Comment: @d03boy: That's right. But I think penalizing people for not constantly hitting Refresh on one thread is sub-optimal. ;-) Even if you intend to undo it later - if I would not have returned before tomorrow the chance to undo it would have been gone, even if I changed my answer then.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would make another table to store any activity. It would simplify things a lot and you could also keep track of deletions and other activities.

Comment: You should look at the whole context before you down-vote people. The question was substantially edited 7 minutes ago, and I have not looked at this thread for at least half an hour. Go figure.

Comment: A comment asking me to do so would have been enough. I'm quite responsive, as you've seen.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would just do a query to each table and select the N most recent items (order by date_added desc limit N), and then merge them in PHP.  That way, you are protected in case you ever need to host the tables on separate physical machines.

You may also ask yourself why you need 3 tables.  Perhaps 1 table with an activity_type column would be enough.  That would probably make it easier to add more activity types later.

Comment: my bad! I've tried to do a simple example but I've done it wrong 'cos I forgot to say that photos table has 4 attributes(user_id,path,photoname,date),videos table has 3 attributes(user_id,youtube_video_url,date) and comments has 3(user_id,comment,date).So we have tables with different number of attr

Comment: how can i do the UNION? and in php how can i understand of wich table the row i'm fetching belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Do a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) on these tables:

```
(SELECT "photo" AS `table`, `date_added` FROM `photos` ORDER BY `date_added` LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT "video" AS `table`, `date_added` FROM `videos` ORDER BY `date_added` LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT "comment" AS `table`, `date_added` FROM `comments` ORDER BY `date_added` LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY `date_added` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```