# mysql - get the last activities of a user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, android-activity

This answer did work but with a problem. [User recent activities - PHP MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561961/user-recent-activities-php-mysql)

My query is same as that

```
(SELECT `user_id`, `date_added`, 'vote' AS `type` FROM `vote` WHERE `user_id` = uid) UNION
 (SELECT `user_id`, `date_added`, 'discussion' AS `type` FROM `discussion` WHERE `user_id` = uid) UNION
 (SELECT `user_id`, `date_added`, 'comment' AS `type` FROM `comments` WHERE `user_id` = uid)
 ORDER BY `date_added` DESC;
```

my tables are votes, comments, discussions. using this query, **I cant get the newly inserted ones, but i get is last - 1 actvity**. how do I take those in to those query?

Comment: can you clarify what you want to get exactly?

Comment: I cant get the newly inserted ones, but i get is last - 1 actvity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT V.user_id, V.date_added, V.vote
FROM vote AS V 
JOIN discussion AS D ON D.user_id=V.user_id
JOIN comments AS C ON C.user_id=V.user_id
ORDER BY V.date_added DESC
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a sample data point for us to look at but I think the problem could be that UNION is removing duplicates and your data points may be same across multiple tables? I'm just making a guess here based on the limited information.

I would suggest using Union ALL instead of UNION and see what data you get back. You can read more about Union and UNION All [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Thanks!